# Syntax highlight in Python in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I am importing Flask using (from flask import Flask) in Python, from is always underlined with a red wavy line as if it were wrong even when the code is correct. 
Any way to fix that? It is getting kind of annoying at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install flask with your python environment.

To do that, open your vscode terminal:

`Terminal` > `New Terminal`

Then:

`pip install flask`

* Sometimes your pip fails installing, you may need to use be root when executing the command.

Then rewrite the from and the red line goes away.

Comment: flask is already installed... have been using it for weeks now

Comment: Try checking your python environments, this only happens when your vscode does not identify that flask is installed.

Comment: it knows its installed but still wont help.